# Babylonnet node continuously restarting (Dockerized version)

Tags: docker, error

I'm working through the B9lab course and I'm setting up a babylonnet node.

The node and updater keep continuously restarting and render me unable to perform any queries to the client.

Here's an image showing the perpetual restart state.

[image: docker error]

Could this error be due to the upgrading of the network to include the Carthage proposal now that Carthage has passed?

**EDIT:** Here is my docker log

[image]

**EDIT2:** Update question for better clarity

Comment: We haven't switch to carthagenet yet. Anyhow, you should include the logs `docker logs <container>`, that will help others help you.

Comment: Thank you, I've included this above.

Comment: I tried this on carthagenet as well and am getting the same error.

Comment: For clarity, understand that "babylonnet", and "carthagenet" are each independent, isolated testing networks/environments. When Carthage goes live, this will happen on "mainnet". "carthagenet" will continue to exist as a standalone testing chain.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Looks like the question has been asked here before and as early as 2 weeks ago there was a fix being implemented: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/627